# How can I remove tabs using PagerSlidingTabStrip?

Tags: java, android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have created an application in android using PagerSlidingTabStrip.

I have created tabs using an adapter and fragments.

When I tried to remove a view using

```
viewPager.removeView(getView());
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The view is hidden but the application shows me an empty view and the tab title persist.

Comment: This would require that your adapter's `getItem`, `getCount`, and `getPageTitle` methods dynamically return the correct value based on which tabs have been deleted.

Comment: Thank you @karaokyo I assumed that but I don't have idea how to do that. Can do you show me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test this, but it would be something along the lines of:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitles.add(title);
    }

    public void removeFragment(int position) {
        mFragments.remove(position);
        mFragmentTitles.remove(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentsTitles.get(position)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank's for your answer. I've tried to solve my problem whit that and remove me the tabs title, but not remove me the view, this persist on the screen but it remove me the last fragment.

Comment: Finally I resolved my problem, using an `FragmentStatePageAdapter`instead a `FragmentPagerAdapter` and using this for screen refresh:

`viewPager.setAdapter(null);
adapter.removeFragment(position);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);`

'

Comment: Could you please post your full solution as an answer and shortly explain, why you had to use FragmentStatePageAdapter instead of a FragmentPagerAdapter? I have the exact same problem with PagerSlidingTabStrip.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out how to do this

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object)
{
    int index = fragments.indexOf(object);
    if (index == -1)
        return POSITION_NONE;
    else
        return index;
}
```

this is the working code!!!